# Can one relate $K_0$ of an $A_\infty$-category $\mathcal A$ to $K_0(Fun_{A_\infty}(\mathcal A, \mathcal A))$?

Tags: homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, derived-categories, mirror-symmetry, a-infinity-algebras

For an $A_\infty$-category $\mathcal A$, one defines the group $K_0(\mathcal A)$ by
$$K_0(\mathcal A) := \mathbb Z \operatorname{Ob} \operatorname{Tw} \mathcal A / \left<[A]+[B]-[C]\right>$$
Where

1) $Tw$ is the twisted complexes category (a way of formally adding all cones, see, https://math.berkeley.edu/~auroux/papers/lec-nantes.pdf section 3.2 for an exposition by Auroux.)

2) The relations are $[A]+[B]-[C]=0$ when $C$ is quasi-isomorphic to a cone of a closed degree 1 morphism $A\to B$

Can one somehow relate $K_0(\mathcal A)$ to $K_0(Fun_{A_\infty}(\mathcal A, \mathcal A))$, i.e. the $K_0$ of the $A_\infty$-category of $A_\infty$-endofunctors?

Thanks